# AMP rel="amphtml" For Dynamic Serving Sites

Tags: amp-html

we have a dynamic serving website that serves a different payload if you're on a mobile device vs a desktop device.

When setting the `rel="amphtml"` on our non-amp pages,  should we put that both on our desktop and mobile versions?

For example, if you are on a desktop device and request our page we will send you a set of HTML and CSS that loads a desktop friendly page. Do we need to use the `rel="amphtml"` on this desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 3 versions of code, one for desktop, another for mobile and third for amp on mobile devices. You should connect them all using below strategy:

put `rel="canonical" href="link-to-desktop-site"` on all 3 versions

put `rel="amphtml" href="link-to-amp-site"` on both non-amp versions, this is good to make search engines understand that you have an amp version for the page. Search engines automatically understand that amp is for mobile-friendly devices only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should put `rel="amphtml"` on your both desktop and mobile versions

***Non AMP Pages [desktop and moobile]***

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/your-amp-content-page.html">
```

***AMP Pages***

```
<link rel="canonical" ref="https://www.example.com/your-non-amp-content-page.html">
```

For more information [**Click Here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery)